Detection of internet connection behind the router: Cable vs. Cellular (4G/5G)
I have this project on my mind:
I've recently installed a 5G router in my office, to serve as a backup/failover internet source, to overcome main/cable internet outages. The backup Xiaomi 5G CPE router works well, and can activate backup internet line within seconds. (app. 2-3 seconds)
My problem is, that the backup cellular line is a metered connection, is slower and less reliable. Therefore, I want to use it as little as possible. Therefore, I need to be informed when my office runs using backup internet connection.
The problem with Xiaomi 5G CPE router is that although it switches to the backup internet swiftly, it does not notifies me about the switch.
I thought, I would program a small tool which would constantly monitor my internet connection (say in 1-seconds-intervals). When it registers that I use cellular connection, I would get notified (email/sound/visual notification...).
However, I would need to know if there is a way to detect that my network runs on cable or cellular internet. Both, the primary cable modem/router and the backup Xiaomi 5G CPE router are connected to the same WAN port behind my office router: To my home Ubuiquiti EdgeRouter is firstly connected the Xiaomi 5G CPE router, into which is then connected the cable modem/router.
Would you have any idea how to detect this? Maybe by analyzing "traceroute" hops?

Hello. Asking us to recommend software products (the library request) is off topic on this site. Also, this is not a script-writing service. If your router supports any sort of scripting you might be able to query which uplink port is active, or you could look for IP ranges. If you're not using a static IP, you would get a general idea what the ranges are for your cable ISP versus your cellular connection and look for those values in your tracert.

Hi @music2myear, understood. Thanks for the tips. So far examining tracert really looks like the best option.

Another option is to use STUN to detect your WAN IP address and classify it as cable vs. cellular based on the returned subnet/range. I use this technique for dynamic DNS updates. Traceroute might be more lightweight though.

Hi @BenHutchison, thanks for the comment. The best solution, I have so far is to ping WAN address of the cable modem/router. If the router is down or if there is outage on the cable network, I think, i should not be able to ping WAN IP address of the cable modem/router. I like that this method is simple, transparent and pretty lightweight.
